# CQWP Cache Issues

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, cache

I'm banging my head on the wall for the CQWP cached issues.

The CQWP is using QueryString from URL to display dynamic content, I noticed if I show ribbon, the content is up-to date no matter I checked out or published the page. However, if I hide the ribbon in any situation, the CQWP is cached. In other word, it won't show anything different from previous cache.

I tried to export CQWP and change useCache to false and have no luck. Is there anyone has similar experience with cached CQWP, or know how to force "show ribbon" open for all visitors?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.sharepointbloggers.com/2011/01/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part.html) might help - apparently it's due to the cache, as you mention in your question.

Other links for you to read:

- [Link 1](https://sharepointhero.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/solving-the-problem-of-delaying-content-in-cqwp/) - this one suggests steps very similar to what you detailed in your question.
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602408/cqwp-renders-only-in-edit-mode/4602449#4602449) - he recommends doing the following:

[image]